# Does changing the type a function returns constitute a backwards incompatible change if behavior remains the same?

Tags: semantic-versioning

If I have a function like `resolve` and in version `1.0.0` of my api and `resolve` returns `SomeObject` and the expectation is `SomeObject` responds to `#success?` and `#failure?` if I were to change `resolve` to return `SomeNewObject` and `SomeNewObject` responds to `#success?` and `#failure?` does this require a bump to the major version of my api? Or because `SomeNewObject` behaves in the exact same way as `SomeObject` am I able to only increment the minor?

It should be noted that this api is in a not strongly typed language (Ruby)

Comment: Does resolve still have the same side effects?  If in the previous version success meant that X was "resolved" to Y, and failure meant it did not resolve to Y, but now success is X resolved to anything but Y, then you've introduced a breaking change, even if it returned the same exact object..

Comment: Yeah it would. I'm essentially wanting to abstract a module with a set of functions into a separate object to reduce the responsibility of the object the functionality currently lives in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The qualifier is if it can break the code. Strictly speaking, a *breaking change* is one that can potentially break the code of those consuming your API. In a non-strongly typed language, if you can guarantee that the objects are sufficiently alike, so if any code that works with `SomeObject` also works with `SomeNewObject`, then this is not a breaking change.

In a strongly typed language, the change in type would be automatically classified as a breaking change because a variable typed `SomeObject` wouldn't be able to receive an object of type `SoneNewObject`. A *non-breaking change* would be if for example you added a new function.

Comment: can you expand on why this is a breaking change if both objects behave in the same way?

Comment: I should probably state this is in not strongly typed language (Ruby)

Comment: Ah, I was about to ask you if this was a strongly typed language. Strictly speaking, if you can guarantee that the two objects are sufficiently alike, so if any code that works with `SomeObject` also works with `SomeNewObject`, then this is not a breaking change. The qualifier is if it can break the code.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the Strongly Typed vs Not Strongly Typed argument so I can accept it?